# Is SmartNet really worth it? What is it?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

My question is regarding Cisco SmartNet. Do I really need this support from Cisco?

I'm a network technician, but I'm in charge of purchasing the network equipment for an upcoming project. I have spec out two WS-C3650-24TS-S Layer 3 switches. The sales rep wants to include this additional charge, but I'm not really sure whether we really need this   Cisco SMARTnet extended service agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only something you can decide for yourself.  Answers are likely to be opinion-based, so this question may be closed as off-topic for this forum.  I will try to give you the facts without the opinion.

The main reasons you *would* get SmartNet are for service, support, and software updates.  If there are bugs in your code version that get updated in later releases, or new features are added to new releases, SmarNet allows you to easily download the new code from CCO.  You can also call CCO for help with the devices covered by the contract.  Cisco will also cover failed devices and replace them for you.

The only real reason you wouldn't get it is cost.  There are several levels of support, from Next Business Day to 2-hour turnaround, and pricing is based on the support level.

Comment: I will, but to closed off, isn't there another way to obtain updates for my CCO. If there are patches or security fixes there is no other way to download them?

Comment: If you are a large enough corporation, you can negotiate a blanket contract with Cisco. SmartNet is Cisco's method to provide you with after-the-sale service and support. New code costs money.

Comment: If there is a published security vulnerability that applies to your hardware, you can contact TAC with the bug ID and hardware serial number for an updated IOS.  But you don't get to pick the IOS level you get access to...   Also it is worth checking the warranty that comes with your hardware, there are software/TAC-support-only options where you depend on the warranty (or your own HW sparing) for failed HW replacement.

Comment: Ironically the warranty lookup site is not even a cisco.com URL: http://www.cisco-servicefinder.com/WarrantyFinder.aspx